# Which statistics analysis should be conducted for a single condition

Tags: statistics

I have recently conducted a study with few participants to understand the feasibility of using voice in coding. Each completed 64 tasks and completion time for each tasks has been recorded. As I am new to statistics, I want to know which statistics analysis method can be best applied in this case.

I have just used qualitative analysis for now but need some quantitative analysis as well.

Any help will be highly appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would depend on the level of measurement of the variables.  Most likely, ANOVA is appropriate, but remember that analysis is driven first by the research question, then the level of measurement of the variables